# Using SHA-256 for CodeIgniter hashing

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, hash, sha256

CodeIgniter uses MD5 or SHA1 for its hashing:

```
$str = do_hash($str); // SHA1

$str = do_hash($str, 'md5'); // MD5
```

**But, my project requires SHA-256. How would I resolve this?**

Comment: The mere existence of the [`do_hash`](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/codeigniter/helpers/security_helper.php.source.html#line58) function really makes me wonder.  `sha1` has been a core function since 4.3.0.  And considering CI requires 5.1.6+, that's a complete sign of code-rot (in my opinion at least)...

Comment: @ircmaxell - It has me wondering now as well.

Comment: Remember guys CodeIgniter has been around for a long time and has been compatible with PHP4 for all of it up until about a month ago. For most of this time it was the only PHP framework to offer PHP5 features to those unfortunate users stuck developing for clients who demand PHP4 compatibility. hash() was introduced in 5.1.2 while do_hash() provides fallbacks and works fine on PHP4. Looks a bit weird today, but it has been bloody useful for years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you not just call php's own hash()?

```
$str = hash ( "sha256", $str );
```

Comment: Yeah, I was answering my own question with: 'why wouldn't I just use php's hash()?' when I saw your answer. So, yup. You are correct.